# Change icon/shortcuts's command line arguments based on Inno Setup components

Tags: inno-setup

Using Inno Setup 6.2, I have icons set up for my app.  Based on `Components` selection, I need to dynamically add switches to the app's cmd line in the icons.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the logic is simple, use [`Components` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/Client"; Components: client
Name: "{autoprograms}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/Server"; Components: server
```

You can reduce code repetition using [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/).

---

If the logic is more complicated, use:

- [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to programmatically modify the parameters;
- [`WizardIsComponentSelected` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected) to query the components selected.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
    Parameters: "{code:GetIconParameters}"
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetIconParameters(Param: String): String;
begin
  if WizardIsComponentSelected('server') then
    Result := '/Server'
  else if WizardIsComponentSelected('client') then
    Result := '/Client'
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```